# Libcurl multithreaded precautions necessary in libcurl multi interface?

Tags: multithreading, libcurl

When using libcurl multithreaded there is a long list of potential problems that can come and bite you in the ass if you're not careful:

> https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/threadsafe.html

What I wonder is simply if the same applies when using the libcurl multi-interface?

> https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html

I would assume that is not the case as the multi-interface runs on the same thread, but I'm not sure, and I can't find it mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't apply exactly for the reasons you state: the multi interface is not using multi-threading by itself.